# How to disable and hide the print and separate and combined pdf download option for docusign signer

Tags: docusignapi

When we send the signing request to Recipient using docusign. Recipient get an option of print, Combined and separate pdf download option in the top header -middle section along with zoom in and out. I want to disable or remove the print and download option for recipient. Is there any way to achieve this in docusign.

Note: I am aware of sign on paper override which hide the print and fax option in other action. And this does not remove or disable the print and download options in the top header.

Thanks
Showji

Comment: The answers on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026627/how-to-hide-print-sign-from-other-actions-menu-in-docusign) also help

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you want to achieve should be possible via modifying the **[Signing Resource File](https://10226ec94e53f4ca538f-0035e62ac0d194a46695a3b225d72cc8.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/docusign-signing-resource-file(v1.1).pdf)**.

Setting these two settings to **false** in the resource file will hide the Download and Print buttons during signing:

- **DocuSign_SigningAllowDownload**
- **DocuSign_SigningAllowPrint**

And, setting these two settings to **false** in the resource file will hide the Download and Print buttons from the "signing complete" view:

- **DocuSignComplete_AllowDownload**
- **DocuSignComplete_AllowPrint**