# How to hide Print & Sign from other actions menu in docusign

Tags: docusignapi

I have a requirement to hide the "Print & Sign" options from OTHER ACTIONS menu. I have followed the Andrew McBride's answer shown in https://support.docusign.com/en/answers/00003891, but it did not help me, still the users are seeing the menu item "Print & Sign". We are not using docusign classic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question. We're not customer support for [your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sending via API, then you need to set below in the envelope definition

```
"enableWetSign":"false"
```

More details available [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/#/definitions/envelopeDefinition)